# Let n be a positive integer. Prove that (n^5)−1 is prime if and only if n = 2

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Can you prove that 
$(n^5)−1$ is prime iff $n=2$? I tried to do so for $n=1$ and $2$ and $3$ and for this but it is only correct for $2$. My teacher said could try for $17$ or $23$ and added that you can prove this with another way

Comment: Proper grammar (like complete sentences, for example) and the use of [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) make posts much more readable.

Comment: I wouldn't see any point in "trying 17 or 23".  Any power of an odd number is odd and subtracting 1 makes it even so they **can't** be prime!

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

We can *always* write

$$n^5-1=(n-1)(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $n^5- 1= (n- 1)(n^4+ n^3+ n^2+ n+ 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider modular congruences. That is, for each natural number $b$, every natural number has the form $qb, qb+1, qb+2...qb+b-1$. Think of it this way- choose a natural number $b$. Then for every natural number $a$, find the greatest multiple of $b$ less than or equal to $a$, say $qb$. Then $a-qb<b$, so you can write this as $qb+r$ with $0\leq r<b$ ($r=a-qb$). See [Euclidean Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) for more.

As a similar example, look at $x^4-1$. Using modular congruences, all numbers have one of the following forms: $3q, 3q+1, 3q+2$ for some $q$. In the first case, $(3q)^4=243q^4$ which is obviously not prime. $(3q+1)^4=81q^4+108q^4+54q^2+12q+1$. Subtracting $1$ from that will give you a multiple of $3$. Finally, $(3q+2)^4=243q^4+216q^3+216q^2+96q+16$. Again, subtracting $1$ will give you a multiple of $3$. The exception to this example occurs when $x^4-1=3$, because $3$ is its only prime multiple. However, if $x^4-1=3$, then $x^4=4$, but $4$ has no integer fourth roots so this is impossible. Now there is a much easier way of doing this as illustrated by the other two answers, but I think it's nice to get some number theoretical insight as well.